# Crash occurring because "CALayer bounds contains NaN: [nan 0; nan 15.1]"

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

I am getting the following crash:

```
CALayerInvalidGeometry CALayerInvalidGeometry
CALayer bounds contains NaN: [nan 0; nan 15.1]
```

on the last line of this code:

```
CGRect bounds = self.bounds;
bounds.size = CGSizeMake(fabsf(self.width), self.height);
self.bounds = bounds;
```

where self.width is derived from a pan gesture recognizer:

```
CGPoint panGestureRecognizerTranslationPoint = [panGestureRecognizer translationInView:panGestureRecognizer.view.superview.superview];

CGPoint rotatedPanGestureRecognizerTranslationPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(panGestureRecognizerTranslationPoint, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-self.angle));
self.width += rotatedPanGestureRecognizerTranslationPoint.x;
```

The one commonality when I get this crash is in the error message, it's always [nan 0; followed by something. Anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Did you log the size and width variables? What data type are they?

Comment: @Wain - They are both CGFloat. No I don't log them, this is a crash report from a user so not sure what values were causing the crash.

Comment: @CoDEFRo see comments on Wain's answer. He asked something.

Comment: @Mani - thanks for the heads up, I responded to him.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> [nan 0; nan 15.1]

This means that the `x` position of the bounds and the `width` are both not numbers. That could mean negative values, or it could be a divide by zero type issue. `nan` of the width could also possibly be a very large width that can't be supported (though that should lead to other error messages).

This kind of thing will often be the result of transforms being applied, either to the values used to create the `bounds` or to the view / layer to which the bounds are applied (as this will modify the applied `bounds` to determine the `frame`).

With rotation transforms, be careful with the `anchorPoint`.

When using view / layer transforms, reset the transform to `identity` before making changes to the `frame`.

Comment: He already tried with `fabsf(self.width)`. then how is it pass negative value?

Comment: Hmm, missed that, are you applying a transform to the view / layer somewhere else in the code?

Comment: @Wain - Yes I am, I'm doing: self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(self.angle); . That line of code occurs after the line where the crash is occurring.

Comment: A negative value is not a NaN. Division by zero is the most common problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `CG_NUMERICS_SHOW_BACKTRACE` environmental variable in the Xcode run scheme and it will dump the stacktrace that caused the non-numeric value to occur.

From there, just investigate why it's happening and guard against it.

Answer (score 2):

in my case I forgot to add images in my project and runtime I was trying to use those images by their name thats why I got this error.

Now its solved after placed the images in project.

Hope this tips helps to others.

Answer (score 1):

Guys! My case was not like this, but close. I've got Nan values in frame rect when I was trying to make UIimageView.
After some searches I figured out that I was initializing frame from nothing - I binded frame to UIimage size, but didn't check if image is not nil. So that's why Nan values appeared in my case.
Check if you pass all values correctly before creating frame from them.

Answer (score 0):

I know you have already found the problem but for those who are facing with the same problem :

I had the same problem. My code was:

```
CGRect rect;
rect.size.width = _mImage.size.width;
rect.size.height = _mImage.size.height;

[_imageView setFrame:rect];
```

When I open the view for the first and second time everything was working fine. But in the third try on the like `[_imageView setFrame:rect]` I had `CALayer bounds contains NaN` So I manually added `x` and `y` for my `rect`:

```
rect.origin.x = 0;
rect.origin.y = 0;
```

So it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The codes below had helped me in my case.

```
 super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10))
```

Please ensure that your CGRect and other Child of UIView size which are passed works properly and have the right values. and Don't forget to turn your Exception debugging modes on.

[image]